# Can "could be" be used for past?

Tags: meaning, sentence-usage

For example,

> 1. I could be asked yesterday.
> 2. We could be asked that time about where we were

Are these sentences correct? Can I not use "could be" to indicate about the past?
Is my second sentence correct? "where we are" or "where we were"?

Comment: I'm afraid, your sentences don't make sense to me. Could you please clarify what point you like to get across?

Answer (score 1):

You can say  *I could have been asked yesterday* if you mean 'there was a possibility yesterday that someone would ask me'. *I could be asked* means that someone could ask you now or in the future.

Your second sentence doesn't make sense either. You can say *We could be asked about where we were that time* (someone could ask us now or in the future about where we were at a particular time in the past).

Comment: Thank you Sir...! I was looking for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is grammatically wrong, it should be "I could *have* asked yesterday"

The second sentence is also wrong, and it should be "We could *have* asked that time about where we were"

You have to use "could have", not "could be"

> where we are or where we were?

You cannot use "where we are", as that is present tense, and you are talking about the past